# Android studio 2.3 generates aar instead of apk

Tags: android, gradle

`Build > Build APK` generates aar instead of apk.

[image: Success window]

In the `outputs` folder I have only the aar folder:

[image: explorer]

My `build.gradle` android section:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.cool.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true;
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

}

What can the problem?

Comment: AAR is the binary distribution of an android library project. It has similar structure as APK.

Comment: @bub yes, I know, but why is this happening? I have an app with some libs, not a library

Comment: Do you have this apply plugin: 'com.android.library' in your gradle? You should have apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: To show what @AndroidRuntimeException is asking about, post the entire Module build.gradle.

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException Yes, I have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` on top of the `build.gradle` file. If I click on `Run 'app'` there are no problems. It launches successfully on the phone.

Comment: Oh, I just realized, that Android Studio's "Show in Explorer" opens the build folder of my library... That's odd. Any ideas?

Comment: The app apk is there, if open it myself from explorer `\app\build\outputs\apk`

Comment: Open your gradle console and check which task are executed when you press Build APK. http://i.imgur.com/tLUdjVE.png

Comment: @AndroidRuntimeException yeah, there is the library task. How do I change this? Could you write this in answer, so I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your Build APK is calling a wrong gradle function. Check your complie options in:

**Android Studio / Preferences / Build, Executions and Deployment / Compiler**

[image: Android Studio / Preferences / Build, Executions and Deployment / Compiler]

Also check your project configurations:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my case, my build.gradle indicated the project was a library and not an application